# PyCharm can't ssh to remote interpreter (com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail)

Tags: ssh, pycharm

I'm trying to connect to a remote python interpreter using PyCharm Professional:

```
PyCharm 2018.1.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-181.4668.75, built on April 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b29 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4
```

Yet, even though I am supplying correct ssh credentials, key, port I keep getting `connection to james@192.168.11.10:22 failed: Authentication failure`. Is there a secret to getting ssh remote interpreter set up on Mac OS?

Here is `sshd` logging showing that I am indeed connecting to the box, but it is being disconnected by `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`. The logs also indicate that the key is indeed matching `authorized_keys`. What gives?

```
Apr 27 13:20:48 james-host sshd[4402]: error: Received disconnect from 192.168.11.1 port 53717:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Apr 27 13:20:48 james-host sshd[4402]: Disconnected from 192.168.11.1 port 53717 [preauth]
```

If I dive deeper into the `sshd` debug...

```
debug1: userauth-request for user james service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "james"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.11.1"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user james service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:5tpn/jFTw9ZRebVhxY4+ogQJDfHn/QN9tFicV6tdHWc [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/james/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK

# Matching key found...
debug1: matching key found: file /home/james/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:5tpn/jFTw9ZRebVhxY4+ogQJDfHn/QN9tFicV6tdHWc
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for james from 192.168.11.1 port 53292 ssh2 [preauth]

# Auth fail??? What?
Received disconnect from 192.168.11.1 port 53292:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Disconnected from 192.168.11.1 port 53292 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 4296
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact problem above, but I was able to get past this problem by two different methods.

1. Enable password authentication via ssh.

I tried this as a diagnostic measure as this is obviously insecure. PyCharm was able to connect.

2. Generate a new ssh-key. Deploy public key to `authorized_keys`.

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

With the new ssh key I was able to successfully connect to a remote Python interpreter. The only difference here is that I did not password protect my private key (it was password protected in my original problem--I will try that next).